# How to model interaction of covariate with time when proportionality assumption is violated in survival analysis in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

In R, what is the best way to incorporate the interaction term between a covariate and time, when the proportionality test (with coxph) shows that the proportionality assumption in the Cox model is violated? I know that you can either use strata or an interaction with time term, I'm interested in the latter. I haven't been able to find a definitive clear explanation with examples on how to do this on the internet. In the most common example using the Rossi dataset, Fox suggested to do,

```
coxph(formula = Surv(start, stop, arrest.time) ~ fin + age + age:stop + prio, data = Rossi.2)
```

Is there a difference between modeling with age:stop versus age:start? Does the formula have to use this format? If I use the Surv with the two parameter format, would the following also make sense?

```
coxph(formula = Surv(week, arrest) ~ fin + age + age:week + prio, data = Rossi)
```

Or you have to split the dataset and use the Surv(start,stop,event) method?
 Also, there is the time-transform method, so,

```
coxph(formula = Surv(week, arrest) ~ fin + age + tt(age) + prio, data = Rossi, tt=function(x,t,...) x*t)
```

I know that some people would prefer model with the `log(t)` instead of `t` here. But which one of these is the correct method to model interaction with time? Do these all refer to the same/different underlying statistical model? And the end, are all modeling (for the interaction term): `h(t) = h0(t)exp(b*X*t)`?

Comment: This is probably too broad as asked. Can you give a more objective criterion for "better"? Otherwise this sounds like an opinion question to me.

Comment: Thank you @BLT. Right now, I am struggling to understand the statistical model that each of these expressions represent (1. Surv with three parameters, and using : term with start or stop, 2. Surv with two parameters, and using : term with time, 3. using tt() term), whether they represent the same model or actually mean different things. I was reading this other blog article (http://daynebatten.com/2016/01/customer-churn-time-dependent-coefficients/) but after reading the comments et al, it was not conclusive on exactly what is correct.

Answer (score 10):

This is essentially a 3 part question:

1. How to estimate time-varying effects?
2. What is the difference between different specifications of time-varying effects using `survival::coxph` function
3. How to decide what shape the time-variation has, i.e., linear, logarithmic, ...

I will try to answer these questions in the following using the veteran data example, which is featured in section 4.2 of the [vignette on time-dependent covariates and time-dependent coefficients](https://cran.microsoft.com/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) (also known as time-varying effects) in the **`survival`** package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(survival)

data("veteran", package = "survival")
veteran <- veteran %>%
  mutate(
    trt   = 1L * (trt == 2),
    prior = 1L * (prior == 10))
head(veteran)
#>   trt celltype time status karno diagtime age prior
#> 1   0 squamous   72      1    60        7  69     0
#> 2   0 squamous  411      1    70        5  64     1
#> 3   0 squamous  228      1    60        3  38     0
#> 4   0 squamous  126      1    60        9  63     1
#> 5   0 squamous  118      1    70       11  65     1
#> 6   0 squamous   10      1    20        5  49     0
```

### 1. How to estimate time-varying effects

There are different popular methods and implementations, e.g. `survival::coxph`, `timereg::aalen` or using GAMs after appropriate data transformation (see below).

Although the specific methods and their implementaitons differ, a general idea ist to create a long form data set where

- the follow-up is partitioned into intervals
- for each subject, the status is 0 in all intervals except the last (if an event)
- the time variable is updated in each interval

Then, the time (or a transformation of time, e.g. log(t)) is simply a covariate and time-varying effects can be estimated by an interaction between the covariate of interest and the (transformed) covariate of time.

If the functional form of the time-variation is known, you can use the `tt()` aproach:

```
cph_tt <- coxph(
      formula = Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno),
      data    = veteran,
      tt      = function(x, t, ...) x * log(t + 20))
```

### 2. What is the difference between different specifications of time-varying effects using `survival::coxph` function

There is no difference. I assume the `tt()` function is simply a short-cut for the estimation via transformation to the long-format. You can verify that the two approaches are equivalent using the code below:

### transform to long format

```
veteran_long <- survSplit(Surv(time, status)~., data = veteran, id = "id",
  cut = unique(veteran$time)) %>%
  mutate(log_time = log(time + 20))
head(veteran_long) %>% select(id, trt, age, tstart, time, log_time, status)
#>   id trt age tstart time log_time status
#> 1  1   0  69      0    1 3.044522      0
#> 2  1   0  69      1    2 3.091042      0
#> 3  1   0  69      2    3 3.135494      0
#> 4  1   0  69      3    4 3.178054      0
#> 5  1   0  69      4    7 3.295837      0
#> 6  1   0  69      7    8 3.332205      0

cph_long <- coxph(formula = Surv(tstart, time, status)~
    trt + prior + karno + karno:log_time, data = veteran_long)

## models are equivalent, just different specification
cbind(coef(cph_long), coef(cph_tt))
#>                       [,1]        [,2]
#> trt             0.01647766  0.01647766
#> prior          -0.09317362 -0.09317362
#> karno          -0.12466229 -0.12466229
#> karno:log_time  0.02130957  0.02130957
```

### 3. How to decide what shape the time-variation has?

As mentioned before, time-varying effects are simply interactions of a covariate `x` and time `t`, thus time-varying effects can have different specifications, equivalent to interactions in standard regression models, e.g.

- `x*t`:  linear covariate effect, linearly time-varying effect
- `f(x)*t`: non-linear covariate effect, linearly time-varying effect
- `f(t)*x`: linear covariate effect, non-linearly time-varying (for categorical x) this essentially represents a stratified baseline hazard
- `f(x, t)`: non-linear, non-linearly time-varying effect

In each case, the functional form of the effect `f` can either be estimated from the data or prespecified (e.g. `f(t)*x = karno * log(t + 20)` above).

In most cases you would prefer to estimate `f` from the data. The support for the (penalized) estimation of such effects is to my knowledge limited in the **`survival`** package. However, you can use `mgcv::gam` to estimate any of the effects specified above (after appropriate data transformation). An example is given below and shows that the effect of `karno` goes towards 0 as time progresses, regardless of the Karnofsky score at the beginning of the follow-up (see [here](https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/articles/tveffects.html) for details and also Section 4.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.01042.pdf)):

```
library(pammtools)
# data transformation
ped <- as_ped(veteran, Surv(time, status)~., max_time = 400)
# model
pam <- mgcv::gam(ped_status ~ s(tend) + trt + prior + te(tend, karno, k = 10),
  data = ped, family = poisson(), offset = offset, method = "REML")
p_2d <- gg_tensor(pam)
p_slice <- gg_slice(ped, pam, "karno", tend = unique(tend), karno = c(20, 50, 80), reference = list(karno = 60))
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p_2d, p_slice, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite an incredible answer, thanks. One question though: in #3, you say that `f` should be estimated from the data. Is trying all common functions (`log`, `sqrt`, `exp`, ...) OK? Else, wouldn't it be possible to guess the functional form by looking at some residuals? (Schoenfeld maybe?). Also, how do you check that the PH problem is corrected after transformation? (since [`cox.zph` is not usable then](https://github.com/therneau/survival/issues/83#issuecomment-529636808))

Comment: the idea is that you don't have to try different functional shapes. You use penalized splines that will estimate the functional form from the data. As you estimate the covariate as potentially time-varying and the functional form is estimated from the data, that is your answer. You don't need to check if PH holds for the covariate because you don't assume PH anymore.

Comment: OK, I assume you are referring to the last example of [`?coxph`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/3.1-8/topics/coxph). I think I understand but if I don't assume PH anymore, wouldn't HR interpretation be different? Or would they still be valid for any specific time?

Comment: well, not really. The last example of coxph is just estimating a non-linear effect of age, but updates the age every year. It's equivalent to include age as a time-varying covariate. One example would be the last example in my answer. You have a non-linear, non-linearly time-varying effect of the `karno` variable. You are right, HR now depends on time, see for example figure on the left panel of the figure. this is the HR of karno 20, 50, 80 relative to karno = 60, each calculated for different time-points.

Comment: See also the vignette for more details: https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/articles/tveffects.html